# Error connecting to Azure SQL Database with Always Encrypted: Failed to decrypt column encryption key using key store provider

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, .net-7.0, always-encrypted

I have an existing API based on .NET 7 with Entity Framework, which is functioning properly. My company plans to implement column encryption, and I have successfully configured it in Azure SQL Database and Azure Key Vault. However, I encountered an error when connecting my API application to the database.

This is the error I got

```
Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: '00-E6-67-F0-EF-A1-85-AD-94-7E'.\r\nInvalid Azure Key Vault key path specified: 'https://{testtest}.vault.azure.net/keys/{testtest}/a5949e32107f409f9a509c5385fb4eed'. Valid trusted endpoints: https://{testtest}.vault.azure.net/. (Parameter 'masterKeyPath')
```

I have tried many solutions from the internet, but unfortunately, the error still persists. Regarding permissions, I have made multiple adjustments to ensure that my Azure-registered application, database, and key vault have access. However, I am not an expert on this matter, and I am still unsure whether the configuration is correct.
[Key Vault Access policies screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUokU.png)

This is my API connection string, code and etc:
Connection string
`"Server=lalalala.database.windows.net;Database=lalala;User=lalala;Password=lalala;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;"`

The current package that I'm using

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" Version="3.0.0" />`

Sample code screenshot

[Sample code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dspo0.png)

The following are the articles or posts that i have lookup

- [Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735293/failed-to-decrypt-a-column-encryption-key-using-key-store-provider-azure-key-v)
- https://khaledelsheikh.medium.com/configuring-always-encrypted-on-azure-sql-by-using-azure-key-vault-and-entity-framework-core-aae687ff2c63

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by removing the second parameter (trusted point).

> var azureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(tokenProvider);

[image: Code update]